# XAML - List of ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm trying to bind a collection of listview in a gridview.

```
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding TimeLines}"                
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Test}">
    </GridView>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Test">        
        <ListView VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Dummy}"                     
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DummyTemplateSelector}"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DummytemStyle}" >
        </ListView>
```

It's work, but i get only one scroll for all the listview.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I need a scroll for each listview,but i have only one scroll for all the listviews

Comment: Try ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" for ListView

Comment: Already tried. Not working :-*(

Comment: Please provide all the needed code to reproduce your issue. There are many StaticResources references, but there are no itselfs. Also Dummy and TimeLines are needed

Comment: What's the parent control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand it you want to have many `ListViews` in one `ListView`. The problem with this is that the outer `ListView` will give each inner `ListView` the Height it needs, so they do not need to show a `ScrollBar`, since they can show all the elements.

If you want to show a `ScrollBar` on the inner `ListViews`, you can limit their Height by setting `MaxHeight`.

Comment: I want many Listviews in one gridview. Actually many columns of listview, having differents height. I set the maxHeight for each listview and it's working. Thank you all for ur help